# Xcode Bitbucket permission error

Tags: permissions, git, xcode, bitbucket.org

Im trying to clone a repository from within Bitbucket by choosing the "Clone in Xcode option".

Xcode then opens and asks for my bitbucket login details, I enter the correct details but i get an error saying

> Your account does not have permission to access this resource

I've tried completely uninstalling Xcode and reinstalling it, I've had our Bitbucket admin assign my account full administrator privileges to the repo.

[Screenshot of Xcode Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivEDG.png)